# Mysqldump with empty result in gzip?

Tags: php, database, compression, gzip, mysql

When I output my MySQL Dump Regularly, it outputs a 30MB File. When I use gzip, 0KB.

Here is my code:

```
$command = "<path to>mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname  | gzip>  test.sql.gz";
system($command);

Result: test.sql.gz 0 KB

---------------------------

$command = "<path to>mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname  > test.sql";
system($command);

Result: test.sql 30 MB
```

Comment: That's odd.  Anything on stderr?  Try adding `2> errors.txt` to the end.

Comment: Do i need to install anything? I mean for gzip?

Comment: Maybe your data just compresses *really, really* well ;)

Comment: You don't check for errors. Are you sure gzip is in the path and is actually run ? You'd be getting a 0 sized file if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to specify a full path to gzip, instead of just gzip?  I'm not sure what your default path will be from within PHP, but it often doesn't cover everything you'd want.